problem getting original emojis from discord [discord.js/discordjs v14]
I am trying to create a discord bot to assign roles based on a reaction to a message from the bot.
I can execute the action using custom emojis like this:
const GET_EMOJI = (name) => client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === name);

But not with the original emojis.
index.js:
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits} = require("discord.js");
const { TOKEN } = require("./config.json");
const ROLE_CLAMED = require("./utils/roleClaimed");

const BOT = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] 
});

BOT.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Hello I'm ready !!!");
    ROLE_CLAMED(BOT);
});

BOT.login(TOKEN);

roleClaimed.js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const FIRST_MSG = require("./firstMsg");

const ROLE_CHANEL_NAME = "roles";

const EMOJIS = {
    // custom emojis
    valorant: "0valo",
    // destiny2: "0dest",
    // LeagueOfLegends: "0lol",
    // original emojis
    test_1: "milky_way",
    // test_2: ":gun:",
    // test_3: ":milky_way:",
}

module.exports = (client) => {
    const CHANNEL = client.channels.cache.find(e => e.name === ROLE_CHANEL_NAME);
    const GET_EMOJI = (name) => client.emojis.cache.find(e => e.name === name);
    const CHOICE = [];
    let txt = "test msg\n\n";

    for (const KEY in EMOJIS) {
        const ROLE = KEY;
        const EMOJI= GET_EMOJI(EMOJIS[KEY]);

        CHOICE.push(EMOJI);
        txt += `${EMOJI} : ${ROLE}\n`;
    }
    FIRST_MSG(CHANNEL, txt, CHOICE)
}

So I have <:emoji_name:emoji_ID> for custom emojis but undefined for discord emojis.
Could you help me solve my problem?
Thanks in advance.

I believe client.emojis.cache doesn't contain default emojis - the default ones are just unicode emojis. Printing out cached emojis with client.emojis.cache.forEach(e => console.log(e)) only gives GuildEmojis when I tried it, and GuildEmoji is only for custom emojis according to discord.js docs.
Could you define the unicode emojis in EMOJIS, then push EMOJIS[KEY] in your example code if EMOJI is undefined?
const EMOJIS = {
    // custom emojis
    valorant: "0valo",
    // rest of your emojis here...
    // unicode emojis
    heart: '❤'
}

module.exports = (client) => {
    const CHANNEL = client.channels.cache.find(e => e.name === ROLE_CHANEL_NAME);
    const GET_EMOJI = (name) => client.emojis.cache.find(e => e.name === name);
    const CHOICE = [];
    let txt = "test msg\n\n";

    for (const KEY in EMOJIS) {
        const ROLE = KEY;
        const EMOJI = GET_EMOJI(EMOJIS[KEY]);
        if (!EMOJI) {
            CHOICE.push(EMOJIS[KEY])
        } else {
            CHOICE.push(EMOJI);
        }
        txt += `${EMOJI} : ${ROLE}\n`;
    }
    FIRST_MSG(CHANNEL, txt, CHOICE)
}

Unsure if your code elsewhere relies on the GuildEmoji type.
Good luck with your bot!
